# can't access stage in flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

I just switched to AS3 I am having problem accessing variables of the timeline from MovieClips. In AS2 we used to do _root.myvar, I checked for references, I found `_root` is `root` now in AS3.

I have a variable `isValid` on the root timeline and My code inside a movieclip needs the value of that variable for some checks. I did this:

MovieClip Frame 1:

```
if(root.isValid == true)
{
 this.gotoAndStop(4);
}
```

It returned some undefined property error on that.

please help

thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the root to a MovieClip:

```
if(MovieClip(root).isValid == true)
{
 this.gotoAndStop(4);
}
```

it should work then..